# What's the difference between "Programmers" and "Stackoverflow" sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meta, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

It escapes me why there are two separate sites with separate reputations and basically the same questions. Does anyone know the rationale behind this separation?
**UPDATE**
Ok, so far the intended difference seems to be that one is for "programmers" and the other for "programming". The distinction is so subtle that you end up with mostly programing questions in "programmers", but separate reputations.

Comment: Basically the same questions? Have you visited both sites?

Comment: The search in stackoverflow didn't turn up anything. With so many sites its confusing (for some reason I ended up in a new one).

Comment: Yes, I have, and the there are programming questions in both, heck, even the same question. I just decided to ignore programmers, because it's pretty much the same than stack overflow, but with less people. I still think the distinction completely artificial and unnecessary. Tell me how this is not a programming question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115614/thread-safe-graph-libraries or any of the questions under design: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design

Comment: The point isn't that design questions aren't programming questions. It's that they are not *implementation* questions. They're the kind of stuff you work out at a whiteboard and that's what Programmers is all about. Far as the thread safe Java library question goes... Those are in a bit of grey area. They're probably on-topic on both SO and Programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [What is the difference between stackoverflow and programmers.stackexchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76890/what-is-the-difference-between-stackoverflow-and-programmers-stackexchange)

Answer (score 1):

See [What's the difference between Stack Overflow and Programmers SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-se)

Answer (score 1):

Compare [this](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).